# Are there security-risks in managing multi-tenancy based on Claims using IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

For some time i've been busy building an identity-server, some complicated structures came up as i'm trying to implemented multi-tenancy.

I would like to know if there are any security-risks regarding the approach im planning to take. Maybe others are struggling as well and could use an example-structure. The following case is present:

- One identityserver
- Multiple tenants with seperate domains
- Multiple user-accounts possible for a user per tenant (Student & Teacher)
- Registered with multiple tenants under differentusernames/email-addresses
- SSO required for all tenants at once

**The structure i had in mind:**
A user is logged in at the Identityserver. The available clients (applications/tenants) for which de id-server can provide authentication are presented like a hub. One is selected (Company3 for example) and the option to link an account for this specific tenant is available.

The user provides an email (Student@company3.com) and a verification is sent to the user. The identityserver-database holds data regarding a one-to-many relationship between a user and the registered client, and a one-to-many between these registrations and the verified email-addresses.

When logging into the identityserver, the token would hold the data for the tenants and the verified accounts. This token is returned and the current client verifies the token using the key from the discovery-endpoint.

**An example of the custom claims would be:**

```
{
"company3":[ "student@company3.com", "teacher@company3.com"]
"company1":[ "student@company1.com", "teacher@company1.com"]
}
```

Company3 would have secure confirmation that the current user has access to 2 accounts. Company1 would have the same information out the token which makes SSO between the different tenants possible.

As i see it, there wouldnt be any security risks. But, im not very experienced with Identity-servers and authentication yet. I would love some feedback regarding possible security risks.

Cheers

Comment: Possibly a question related to https://serverfault.com/ instead of SO.

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/intro/support.html Nope, need to be here

Comment: @Revlyn This seems to be a quite complex topic and a very unspecific question that can't be answered without digging deep into your architecture. I don't think you can expect an answer here or over at github where you have linked to here. To me it sounds like you're on a good way to solve your problem. Maybe lay out more details and some drawing to improve your own understanding of the setup, then ask a real specific question that can be answered with yes/no.

Comment: I'm in the same boat ! Have you had any success with the above approach? If you separate the user based on Tenant(I assume client), then how do you achieve SSO, unless if you keep adding user per client/s. but this sounds like a easiest option. however this requires a custom implementation of most of the idsrv endpoint to consider a "check is user belongs to this client?" also different cookies (bit complex one idsrv instance multiple logins using multiple tenants on the same browser)